# FTP Troubleshooting

Tags: centos, ftp, nat

I have a centos 6.5 installed on Virtual Box. I'm trying to configure a basic ftp server. Below are details of it.

1. Installed vsftpd from DVD/Yum: Status -> Successful
2. Disabled firewall for test purposes,

   ```
   chkconfig iptables off : successful

   service iptables stop : successful
   ```
3. Also set selinux in disabled mode: successful
4. Added a rule in VirtualBox for port forwarding over NAT:

   ```
   Rule Protocol Host Port Guest Port
   Ftp  tcp.     2121.     21
   ```

---

### Now when I try to connect with local user or anonymous, it gives a number of errors, every time a different error.

I'm also adding log messages shown by Filezila on my Host machine.

-> LocalUserLogFromClient

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of localhost
Status: Connecting to [::1]:2121...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by
server", trying next address.
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2121...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Welcome to C6G FTP service.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Command:    AUTH SSL
Response:   530 Please login with USER and PASS.
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command:    USER FUser1
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS *****
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

-> AnonymousUserLog

```
Status: Resolving address of localhost
Status: Connecting to [::1]:2121...
Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by
server", trying next address.
Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2121...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (10,0,2,15,88,204).
Command:    LIST
Error:  The data connection could not be established: 10065
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: (a) Is your client using passive mode?; (b) Does the NAT have a protocol helper for FTP? It needs one, or FTP won't work (FTP is hard to NAT); and (c) Let's have a few of those errors. A protocol log would be great.

Comment: @derobert hi there, thanks for your kind reply. Yes it does say something about passive mode in connection messages. I tried using filezila & fireftp extension of Firefox browser too. I'll update the errors next morning, as I'm using my cell phone right now, hope you don't mind waiting.

Comment: @derobert what is a protocol helper? Does VirtualBox need it too? If yes how is it configured?

Comment: @casey thank you, do both of these (active/passive) need a different type of setup or configuration? If so, how it's done?

Comment: @Sollosa a protocol helper "listens in" on the connection, and rewrites embedded IP addresses, opens related ports, etc. No idea how to set one up in VirtualBox. With Linux NAT, you'd load the ftp connection tracking module.

Comment: @casey In active mode, client connects to server, tells the server which IP address and port to connect to for data transfer, then requests some data. In passive mode, client connects to server, asks the server for an IP address and port to connect to for data transfer, requests some data transfer, then connects to the server-provided IP and port. So in passive mode, a server needs either a NAT helper or special configuration, and it also needs more open incoming ports.

Comment: @derobert sounds complicated to me. I added 2nd network interface to link all vms in one internal network with static IPs & corresponding netmask & gateway values assigned to each machine. Then tried to connect to ftp from an internal client machine, but did not succeed either. Btw all machines can ping/ssh eachother, but ftp still not accessible.

Comment: @Sollosa we'll need logs from that one to troubleshoot. Unfortunately FTP is a annoyingly complicated protocol w/r/t NAT.

Comment: @derobert ok, so where do I look for output of those logs? Are those ftp logs in xferlog file or do I have to send ftpclient outputs?

Comment: @Sollosa you're going to want to grab both. Main thing would be a protocol log, showing a transcript of the FTP control connection.

Comment: @derobert hi again, I looked at xferlog file in my machine, but is empty. But following are the output of screen messages shown by filezila when I connect through my host machine.

Comment: @derobert wish I could add screenshots here, but this is the output.

Comment: @Sollosa you can add screenshots (and any other additional information) by using the [edit] link under your question (or that one in my comment)

Comment: @derobert I'm trying to configure how to add screen shots, maybe it's one of earnable privilege here. But anyway I updated the client outputs in my question as well. Please check it and help me, thanks.

Comment: @Sollosa You should be able to with the image button above the edit box. I tested as a not-logged-in (and thus no rep user) and it works. Anyway, I think the transcripts are enough, unless there is something else in the screenshots.

Comment: @derobert so do you suggest me to add more than 20sin default connection time out in FTP's configuration file? Would it work then? Actually my ssh request to virtual machine also get lags & connects late. I checked ftp on machine's console & it's working fine. But doesn't from the host machine.

Comment: @Sollosa You could up the timeout in the *client* (if it has an option for that), that could work around your first problem (but an authentication response really ought to take well under a second, not more than 20.)

Comment: @derobert I see, I'll check to see with time issue & get back at you, till then have good time & thanks for all the time & your help efforts. Appreciate that, highly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An FTP server behind a port forwarder can’t serve in the passive mode unless the software used has a *special design* to pass FTP data connections through. Cases are:

- The NAT software able to sniff for `227 Entering Passive Mode` in FTP control connection, to do port forwarding accordingly and some mangling of FTP control data.
- The FTP server sending passive mode with visible (NAT) IP address and the NAT forwarding given range of ports.
  Thanks to @derobert for pointing out a flaw in my original reasoning.

Linux kernel NAT is supplied with an (optional) FTP support. But if Linux is the *guest*, then its NAT has nothing to with the problem. The host system’s NAT must do NAT for the guest, indeed. Has the Windows’ NAT software in question such capability? Dunno, and it’s not a Linux question anyway. Recommended solution: replace NAT with bridging for the virtual machine.

Comment: It doesn't have to be done in the NAT. You can often configure the server to send passive mode with its public, routable IP address and a given range of ports, then you just need to make sure those ports are forwarded through the NAT. I'd say this is often the preferred config, as it greatly reduces resource requirements and attack surface on the NAT box (often the firewall). Does make a more complicated setup, though, so depends on the size of the setup, and how many connections you expect.

Comment: @Incnis Mrsi I've tried Bridged network too, I can ping &  access centos machines via ssh. FTP works fine on the console of the machine, but if I access it from host machine with its IP, it says failed to load directory listings.

Comment: @Sollosa: Ask a follow-up question. Solution for your *original* problem is achieved, isn’t it?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi well yes question answered but issue still unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

Your logs show two different problems:

1. For the non-anonymous user, the login timed out. After 20s of waiting for the login to complete, your FTP client gave up. This probably means your authentication configuration (on the server) is not working—especially if you tried to set up virtual users, etc. Other than that, the server might be taking a long time to write to a log, or maybe perform a DNS resolution.
2. Your anonymous user log is probably having a NAT issue. `227 Entering Passive Mode (10,0,2,15,88,204).` means that the client needs to make a connection to 10.0.2.15:22732/tcp, and its reporting it timed out. That's an odd address to have to connect to, since the FTP connection itself is to localhost.

<sup>(BTW: the last two numbers are two bytes of the port number, in network byte order. So 88×256 + 204 = 22732.)</sup>